# Loop until variable is isset then excute a code

Tags: php

I try to do a while loop but something is missing I need to loop until variable is isset then execute a code something like dis :

```
$counter=o;
while(null!==($var)){


$counter ++;
}
if (isset($var)){
excute code ....

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You mean like [this](https://eval.in/619728)?

```
$counter = 0;
while (!isset($var)) {
    $counter ++;
    echo $counter, PHP_EOL;
    if ($counter == 10) {
        $var = true;
    }
}

echo 'Done', PHP_EOL;
```

I suggest you don't use the existance of a variable to control your logic flow - using something like a `break` command to kill your potentially infinite loop might be better, for example:

```
while (true) {
    // do something
    if ($someCondition) {
        break;
    }
}
```